# ¿Cómo funciona las variables globales en la built-in function try-except?

Tags: python, variables, excepciones, variables-globales, try-catch

Estoy haciendo un programa que pide la cantidad de problemas que “x” usuario desee realizar, como lo puedes ver a continuación:

```
print('¿Cuántos problemas deseas realizar?')

while True:
    global cantidad_problemas
    try:
        cantidad_problemas = int(input('>> '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f'> {cantidad_problemas} no es un número entero.')

print(cantidad_problemas)
```

En la sección “try” el programa le pide al usuario que introduzca un número entero, y si por algún motivo se equivoca, el programa se lo dice en la sección ‘except”. Pero cuando intento que el programa le indique al usuario cual fue el input que tecleó, me sale esto:

```
NameError: name 'cantidad_problemas' is not defined
```

Sé que la variable “cantidad_problemas” es una variable local de la sección ‘try”, por eso antes de iniciar esa sección, establecí la variable “cantidad_problemas” como global pero igual me sigue dando el mismo error.
El programa le podría decir al usuario que simplemente se equivocó, pero me gustaría que mostrase el error que cometió el usuario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Sé que la variable “cantidad_problemas” es una variable local

No es una variable local, al contario la estás definiendo como global, la manera en la que lo escribes me da a entender que no existe una definición previa de `cantidad_problemas`, por lo tanto, si bien estás indicando que la variable va a ser global, no la estás inicializando hasta que haces `cantidad_problemas = int(input('>> '))` (si es que no existe una definición previa). Mira este ejemplo, en el siguiente código declaro que `prueba` es una variable global, pero no la inicializo en ningún lado... Por lo tanto la variable no está definida:

```
global prueba
print(prueba)
```

Al correrlo cómo resultado obtenemos:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 15, in <module>
NameError: name 'prueba' is not defined
```

Ahora mira lo que ocurre en el siguiente código, en donde inicializo la variable global con antelación:

```
prueba = 1

def funcionPrueba():
    global prueba
    print(prueba)
    
funcionPrueba()
```

Resultado:

```
1
```

Cómo puedes ver lo que está haciendo falta es la inicialización de la variable. Ahora, viene la otra pregunta, si esto es cierto

### ¿Porqué entonces `cantidad_problemas = int(input('>> '))` no la inicializa?

Y la respuesta tiene que ver con tu mismo `try` block... Nunca se realiza la asignación, por eso "atrapas" el error con el `except`, cuando haces el `int()` de por ejemplo una `string` como `"a"` el código falla y no puede realizar la asignación, entonces `cantidad_problemas` nunca fue asignado.

Ahora antes de darte una solución se me ocurre que usaste `global` porque creíste que lo que pasaba era que la variable no existía en el `scope` del `except`, pero este no es el caso, entonces no lo necesitas.

Para solucionarlo creo que lo mejor sería primero asignar la variable con el input y LUEGO hacer el parsing (`int()`), de esta manera si el `parsing` falla aún así tienes tu variable ya definida para hacer el print en el `except`, así:

```
print('¿Cuántos problemas deseas realizar?')

while True:
    try:
        cantidad_problemas = input('>> ')
        cantidad_problemas = int(cantidad_problemas)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print(f'> {cantidad_problemas} no es un número entero.')

print(cantidad_problemas)
```

¡Espero que esto te sea de ayuda! Por cierto saludos desde Costa Rica, no veo a tanta gente de acá en el sitio.

Comment: en resumen `global` solo hace que el *scope* de la variable sea global y pueda ser accedida desde cualquier parte, además también se puede cambiar su *scope*, si en una función la indicas como `nonlocal` su *scope* cambiara

Comment: @Christian No, esto no es un resumen de mi respuesta. Podrías usar `global` e igual el código funcionaría... Como especifiqué en la respuesta esto no es un problema de `scope`, el problema real es que no se logra definir la variable porque el error ocurre antes de la inicialización de la misma. Por lo tanto no se puede imprimir.

Comment: acabo de leerla nuevamente y si, bueno el problema también se soluciona si se le da un valor después de hacerla global, ¿o no?

Comment: Eso es lo que hace el OP, si te refieres a un valor "default" en ese caso ya no tendría sentido si quiera hacer el `print`. Entonces no lo veo como una buena solución.